# SFDX source push failing on Duplicate picklist value

Tags: scratch-org, sfdx-error, source-push

As of today (6/7/2022) the `sfdx force:source:push` command started failing after scratch org creation as part of the deployment script we're using in our pipeline.

It throws the following errors back:

[image]

It's happening on every push and the picklist is almost always a different one. Is there someone else getting the `Duplicate picklist value` error back as well out of nowhere? And ideally, did you find how to fix this? So far I wasn't really successful as the same metadata worked fine yesterday.

**7/7/2022 Update** - the source is pushed as expected again, both locally and as part of the deployment pipeline

Comment: Did you by any chance rename a bunch of picklist API values while leaving the label intact?

Comment: No, everything is the same as it was when it still worked yesterday. Pushing from the same branch which was not touched...

Comment: Just wondering if it might be a global issue, so wondering if someone else is having the same issue as of today.

Comment: Did you update your sfdx CLI version since yesterday (or is that something your CI pipeline always does)? Have you tried creating a new scratch org today, manually, and pushing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a ticket on the SFDX CLI repo here. Adding a comment may help to increase visibility:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1605

Here are additional links to places this issue is being discussed:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000HEAATSA5
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000HEACASA5
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000HEAGrSAP

Comment: Update: This issue appears to be resolved. http://status.salesforce.com/incidents/9417